# Not selected 'hr' default database during installation

Tags: oracle12c

I have installed oracle database 12c on linux , during installation i forgot to enable hr schema so now is there way to enable 'hr' after installation or i have to install it all again ?

Comment: See the documentation: [Installing sample schemas](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/comsc/installing-sample-schemas.html#GUID-1E645D09-F91F-4BA6-A286-57C5EC66321D).

Comment: @AlexPoole this shows how to unlock the database that we select during installation but i haven't selected that during installation so i want to know that can we do that after installation.

Comment: Section 2.1.1 talks about that. Did you read the rest, particularly 2.1.2 - ["Manually installing the HR Schema"](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/comsc/installing-sample-schemas.html#GUID-CB945E4C-D08A-4B26-A12D-3D6D688467EA)?